# How to specify an equation with BDD

Tags: cucumber, bdd

Lets say there is a feature to calculate a result based on values of several variables and there is an equation which specifies how to calculate the result.

Now, I need to write a scenario in BDD given when then syntax and write tests using cucumber to test this scenario written in BDD syntax.

For writing the scenario, I can think of two options.

1. Write a single scenario which captures all details in the equation, so that the equation itself can be derived from the scenario.
2. Write multiple scenarios by applying various values to the variables in the equations and writing the expected result.

Option 1 is very difficult to write, but it captures the equation in it.

Option 2 is easier to understand, but the equation itself is not defined anywhere in the scenario. Since my company instructs to write all specs as BDD scenarios, there is nowhere else where I can write the equation in a spec.

Which option is the correct way? Or is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scenarios are specific examples which *illustrate* the requirements (or the definition).

Most people put the "rules" for their scenarios - the equation definition, the acceptance criteria, or the rationale behind the behaviour - in the blurb at the top of the feature file.

So for instance, if I were writing Conway's Game of Life, I might have a feature file like this:

```
Feature: Rules for cells
  Cells die if there are fewer than 2 neighbours (lonely)
  Cells die if there are more than 3 neighbours (starving)
  Cells are born in empty spaces with 3 neighbours

Scenario: Lonely cells die
  Given a grid which looks like
    ........
    .X......
    ....XX..
    ........
```

Etc.

So in your case, your feature file can contain the definition of the equation, and the scenarios are specific examples of the equation in action.

```
Feature: My Equation
    x = 3y + max(z, u)

Scenario: z is bigger than u
    Given y = 3, z = 10 and u = 5
    When I calculate the result
    Then x should be 19.
```

I'm guessing your equation's probably more complicated than this, but hopefully it gives you the idea.